# Print all even values in all object key end with odd value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I want to print all even values in all object key end with odd value but the coding I made just now is only specified for arr1, arr3, and arr5. Can anyone suggest me how to fix  'let oddArr' method (maybe in loop) so that when I changed arr1 into arr7, the result would be the same.

```js
var num = {
    arr1 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    arr2 : [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    arr3 : [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    arr4 : [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
    arr5 : [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
    };

    let oddArr = [...num.arr1, ...num.arr3, ...num.arr5] //need some correction here
    let evenNum = oddArr.filter(number => number % 2 == 0);

    console.log(evenNum.toString());
    
    //help me fix 'let oddArr' (maybe in loop method) so that when I changed the object of the array (e.g: arr1 -> arr7) it would come out with the same result 
    
    //the result/output should be 2,4,6,8,10,22,24,26,28,30,42,44,46,48,50 based on var num
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below using for in loop and it works with any last character as odd.

```
var num = {
  arr1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  arr2: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  arr3: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
  arr4: [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
  arr7: [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
};

let oddArr = [];
for (let key in num) {
  if (key.charAt(key.length - 1) % 2 !== 0) {
    oddArr = [...oddArr, ...num[key]];
  }
}

let evenNum = oddArr.filter((number) => number % 2 === 0);

console.log(evenNum.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: it works! thank you so much!! I just take a look for charAt loop method and gladly you came up with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use

```
let oddArr = Object.entries(num).filter(   // filter key names
   e => +e[0].replace("arr", '') % 2 !== 0 // replace "arr" and check if X in arrX is odd
).map(e => e[1]).flat()                    // merge values and flattern array
```

You can also make use of regex if the "arrX"-naming is not consistent:

```
+e[0].match(/\d+/) % 2 !== 0
```

See a working snippet below:

```js
var num = {
  arr1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  arr2: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  arr3: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
  arr4: [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
  arr5: [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
};

let oddArr = Object.entries(num).filter(
  e => +e[0].replace("arr", '') % 2 !== 0
).map(e => e[1]).flat()

let evenNum = oddArr.filter(number => number % 2 == 0);
console.log(evenNum.toString());
```

Comment: hello there! thank you so much for your answers and i'm so glad for that. can you enlighten me a bit about the code especially at .map(e => e[1]).flat() ? what method did you use? it's just for me to learn a lil bit more since i'm kinda new with this. thank you in advance!

Comment: `.map(e => e[1]).flat()` converts back the Object.entries array to a values only array to get rid of the "arrX"-string. `Array.prototype.flat()` flatterns the array since it is multidimensional and we just want  to get back the single values next to each other.

Comment: okay now I get it, thank you so much for sharing!

Answer (score -1):

This also works.

```js
var num = {
  arr1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  arr2: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  arr3: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
  arr4: [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
  arr5: [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
  arr6: [51, 52, 53, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
  arr7: [61, 62, 63, 66, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
};

var evenNums = Object.keys(num).filter((item) => {
    itemNum = item.replace("arr", "");
    return itemNum % 2 !== 0;
}).map((o) => num[o]).flat().filter((x) => x % 2 == 0);

console.log(evenNums);
```